# Django queryset latest object's attributes after group by

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my model

```
class MyLog(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  comment = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

What i am trying to do is group by email, then filter the query by repetitions greater than 5 after that get the comment field's value of the latest object (from latest date value). I am not able to acheive the last part. Here my query so far

```
MyLog.objects.values("email").annotate(Count("id")).filter(id__count__gte=5)
```

This much is correct I am getting output like

> <QuerySet [{'email': 'test@test.com',  'id__count': 6,}]>

How can I query the latest comment ? I am not able to figure out how to query that. Below is what I am looking for.

> <QuerySet [{'email': 'test@test.com',  'id__count': 6, 'comment': 'nice article'}, {'email': 'test1@test.com',  'id__count': 7, 'comment': 'Good one'}]>

**UPDATE**

```
logs = MyLog.objects.values("email").annotate(Count("id")).filter(id__count__gte=5)
logs_with_latest_comment = MyLog.objects.order_by("email", "-date").values(
                "email",
                "comment",
            ).distinct("email")

comment_dict = dict()
for comment in logs_with_latest_comment:
  comment_dict[comment["email"]] = comment["comment"]

for log in logs:
  log.update({"comment": comment_dict[log["email"]]})
```

This way I got the expected result. But still looking for a cleaner solution perhaps with a single query ?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no elegant solution that can produce one result set as you expect (also one database hit ?) at django ORM level, unless you write raw SQL, which highly depend on your database backend (e.g. MySQL, postgreSQL ... etc.)

Here's what you can do at ORM level :

- annotate one more field `Max('date')` , to generate one queryset (qset1)
- identify last-updated logs, fetch other fields, by using `Max('date')` and `email` in the lookup condition
- manually combine qset1 and qset2 in your code

Quick example:

```py
# generate  2 fields id__count, date__max, will use date__max in later step
qset1 = MyLog.objects.values("email").annotate(Count("id"), Max('date')).filter(id__count__gte=5)

# use date__max as part of condition to identify last-updated log of each email, but it lacks id__count fields
qset2 = MyLog.objects.filter(email__in=qset1.values_list('email', flat=True)  , date__max__in=qset1.values_list('date__max', flat=True))

# for adding `id__count`, combine qset1 and qset2 into one single result set
```

Comment: this can give the latest object only. I have updated the question. Please see the expected output.

Comment: sample code updated, to get value of certain fields, you can simply append field name to  positional arguments of `values()`

Comment: this is actually generating group by two fields email and comment. I want to just group by email only. and the latest returns only one object. I want multiple objects. Here is what am looking for "select unique emails and get count of the emails also retrieve the latest comment by user having this email".

Comment: thanks for putting your time on my question. I was trying to find a solution from yesterday. Like you mentioned it seems it is difficult to get it in a single query. I have got another solution with multiple queries which updated in the question. Seems it is working.